# Sleekxmpp subscription and eventing not working for same user session

Tags: python, xmpp, publish-subscribe

I am trying to implement pub sub using sleek xmpp. Below is the code for publish and subscribe refactored from examples under sleek xmpp. What I am doing is I am subscribing to node n1 of user1/resourceA (creator of the node) from the session by user1/resourceB. The problems are

- When I  publish msg from user1/resourceA , I am not getting the event for node n1 in user1/resourceB eventhough subscription is successful.
- When I do a publish from user1/resourceB to node n1, I get the event publish from the same session but not to the other session. ie subscribe to node n1 from user1/resourceA who is the creator of node . In this case I am getting the events.

  ```
  def create(self,node_name,config=None):
    try :        
        self['xep_0060'].create_node(self.pubsubserver,node_name,config=config)
   except:
        logging.error('Could not create node: %s' % node_name)

  def publish(self,node_name,payload,_id=None):
        print 'entering pubsub publish'
        payload_xml = ET.fromstring("<test xmlns='test'>%s</test>" % payload)
        ET.dump(payload_xml)
        try:
           result = self['xep_0060'].publish(self.pubsubserver, node_name,payload=payload_xml)

      except:
           logging.error('Could not publish to: %s' % node_name)
  def subscribe(self,node_name,cb,options=None):
     try:
         self['xep_0060'].map_node_event(node_name,node_name)
         self.add_event_handler('n1_publish',cb)
         result = self['xep_0060'].subscribe(jid=self.pubsubserver, node=node_name)
         print('Subscribed to node %s' % (node_name))
     except:
         logging.error('Could not subscribe')
  ```

logs :

```
#logs for create node n1
  xmlstream: 1728 SEND: <iq to="xmppserver.com" type="set"  id="test@xmppserver.com/testff388888-4563-11e4-ad83-3c970eebb17011"><pubsub xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub">
   <create node="n1" /></pubsub></iq>
   xmlstream: 1603 RECV: <iq from="xmppserver.com" type="result" id="test@xmppserver.com/testff388888-4563-11e4-ad83-3c970eebb17011" to="test@xmppserver.com/testff388888-4563-11e4-ad83-3c970eebb170" />


 #logs for subscribe to node n1 from session2 
    xmlstream: 1728 SEND: <iq to="xmppserver.com" type="set" id="test@xmppserver.com/test2d487986-4564-11e4-b710-3c970eebb1707"><pubsub xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub"><subscribe node="n1" jid="test@xmppserver.com" /></pubsub></iq>
    xmlstream: 1603 RECV: <iq from="xmppserver.com" type="result" id="test@xmppserver.com/test2d487986-4564-11e4-b710-3c970eebb1707" to="test@xmppserver.com/test2d487986-4564-11e4-b710-3c970eebb170"><pubsub xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub"><subscription node="n1" jid="test@xmppserver.com" subscription="subscribed"><subscribe-options /></subscription></pubsub></iq>


 #logs for publish to node1 from session1
  publish n1 session1
  test_pubsub: 59 publish to node n1 with data session1 :
  entering pubsub publish
  <ns0:test xmlns:ns0="test">session1</ns0:test>
  <iq to="xmppserver.com" type="set" id="test@xmppserver.com/testff388888-4563-11e4-ad83-3c970eebb17013"><pubsub xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub"><publish node="n1"><item><test xmlns="test">session1</test></item></publish></pubsub></iq>
  xmlstream: 1728 SEND: <iq to="xmppserver.com" type="set" id="test@xmppserver.com/testff388888-4563-11e4-ad83-3c970eebb17013"><pubsub xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub"><publish node="n1"><item><test xmlns="test">session1</test></item></publish></pubsub></iq>
  xmlstream: 1603 RECV: <iq from="xmppserver.com" type="result" id="test@xmppserver.com/testff388888-4563-11e4-ad83-3c970eebb17013" to="test@xmppserver.com/testff388888-4563-11e4-ad83-3c970eebb170" />
  xmlstream: 1603 RECV: <message to="test@xmppserver.com" from="test@xmppserver.com" id="n1__test@xmppserver.com__fE85u"><event xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#event"><items node="n1"><item id="4be1b29a-4af8-4456-a5c8-0a311dabce4937"><test xmlns="test">session1</test></item></items></event></message>

xmlstream: 1156 Event triggered: pubsub_publish
test_pubsub: 36 1. create  <node name>
xmlstream: 1603 RECV: <message to="test@xmppserver.com" from="test@xmppserver.com" id="n1__test@xmppserver.com__fE85u"><event xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#event"><items node="n1"><item id="4be1b29a-4af8-4456-a5c8-0a311dabce4937"><test xmlns="test">session1</test></item></items></event></message>
```

I am using Openfire server for Xmpp